# Parse large json data in Java with arrays and strings in json values

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, large-data

The json string generated from the media server looks like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "albums": [
            {
                "albumid": 1,
                "albumlabel": "",
                "artist": [
                    "www.SongsLover.pk"
                ],
                "artistid": [
                    2
                ],
                "description": "",
                "genre": [
                    "Pop"
                ],
                "label": "Single 2012",
                "rating": 0,
                "style": [
                    ""
                ],
                "thumbnail": "image://music@smb%3a%2f%2fCECOTS-NAS%2fMedia%2fMusic%2fbackup%20Music%2fSissle2%2fGangnam%20Style%20.mp3/",
                "title": "Single 2012",
                "type": "",
                "year": 0
            },
            {
                "albumid": 164,
                "albumlabel": "",
                "artist": [
                    "ARrahman","MJ"
                ],
                "artistid": [
                    146,163
                ],
                "description": "",
                "genre": [
                    "Soundtrack"
                ],
                "label": "Lord of the rings",
                "rating": 0,
                "style": [
                    ""
                ],
                "thumbnail": "image://music@smb%3a%2f%2fCECOTS-NAS%2fMedia%2fMusic%2fExtras_Test%2fEnakkena%20Yenave.mp3/",
                "title": "Lord of the rings",
                "type": "",
                "year": 2000
            },{..........},{........},{........}
        ],
        "limits": {
            "end": 155,
            "start": 0,
            "total": 155
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the code i tried using Java. Iam getting the json response as **Input stream** and using jsonreader to parse the json response. But here in the above json, the **artist** dictionary has array values without names.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                        "UTF-8"));
ArrayList<Integer> albumId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> artistId = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String name = reader.nextName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
                    reader.beginObject();
                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        String check = reader.nextName();

                        if (check.equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                            reader.beginArray();
                            int i = 0;
                            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                i++;

                                    reader.beginObject();
                                    int albumid;
                                    String artistid = null;

                                    while (reader.hasNext()) {

                                        name = reader.nextName();
                                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("albumid")) {
                                            albumid = reader.nextInt();
                                            albumId.add(albumid);
                                        } else if (name
                                                .equalsIgnoreCase("artist")) {
                                            reader.beginArray();
                                            while(reader.hasNext()){
                                                artistid = reader.nextString();
                                                artistId.add(artistid);
                                            }
                                            reader.endArray();
                                        }  else {
                                            reader.skipValue();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    reader.endObject();
                                //}
                            }
                            Log.i(LOGCAT, Integer.toString(i));
                            reader.endArray();
                        } else {
                            reader.skipValue();
                        }
                    }

                    reader.endObject();
                } else {
                    reader.skipValue();
                }
            }
            reader.endObject();
```

So, the problem for me is how to get the array values from the **artist** dictionary with the above code. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a decent JSON library (ie, Jackson for instance, or Gson) and create POJOs; deserialize to these POJOs directly

Comment: Ok fge, i will follow up. is there any way to achieve the output with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will you to solve your problem...

        String respone = "{\"id\":1,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":{\"albums\":[{\"albumid\":1,\"albumlabel\":\"\",\"artist\":[\"www.SongsLover.pk\"],\"artistid\":[2],\"description\":\"\",\"genre\":[\"Pop\"],\"label\":\"Single 2012\",\"rating\":0,\"style\":[\"\"],\"thumbnail\":\"image://music@smb%3a%2f%2fCECOTS-NAS%2fMedia%2fMusic%2fbackup%20Music%2fSissle2%2fGangnam%20Style%20.mp3/\",\"title\":\"Single 2012\",\"type\":\"\",\"year\":0},{\"albumid\":164,\"albumlabel\":\"\",\"artist\":[\"ARrahman\",\"MJ\"],\"artistid\":[146,163],\"description\":\"\",\"genre\":[\"Soundtrack\"],\"label\":\"Lord of the rings\",\"rating\":0,\"style\":[\"\"],\"thumbnail\":\"image://music@smb%3a%2f%2fCECOTS-NAS%2fMedia%2fMusic%2fExtras_Test%2fEnakkena%20Yenave.mp3/\",\"title\":\"Lord of the rings\",\"type\":\"\",\"year\":2000}],\"limits\":{\"end\":155,\"start\":0,\"total\":155}}}";

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> albumList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        try{
            JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(respone);
            JSONArray albumJsonArray = responseJson.getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("albums");

            for (int i=0;i<albumJsonArray.length();i++){
                HashMap<String,Object> album = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                album.put("albumid",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("albumid"));
                album.put("albumlabel",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("albumlabel"));

                JSONArray artistJsonArray =  new JSONArray(albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("artist"));
                ArrayList<String> artistList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j=0;j<artistJsonArray.length();j++){
                     artistList.add(artistJsonArray.getString(j));
                }
                album.put("artist",artistList);

                JSONArray artistidJsonArray =  new JSONArray(albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("artistid"));
                ArrayList<String> artistidList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j=0;j<artistidJsonArray.length();j++){
                    artistidList.add(artistidJsonArray.getString(j));
                }
                album.put("artistid",artistidList);

                album.put("description",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));

                JSONArray genreJsonArray =  new JSONArray(albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("genre"));
                ArrayList<String> genreList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j=0;j<genreJsonArray.length();j++){
                    genreList.add(genreJsonArray.getString(j));
                }
                album.put("genre",genreList);
                album.put("label",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("label"));
                album.put("rating",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rating"));

                JSONArray styleJsonArray =  new JSONArray(albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("style"));
                ArrayList<String> styleList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j=0;j<styleJsonArray.length();j++){
                    styleList.add(styleJsonArray.getString(j));
                }
                album.put("style",styleList);
                album.put("thumbnail",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("thumbnail"));
                album.put("title",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                album.put("type",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("type"));
                album.put("year",albumJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("year"));

                albumList.add(album);
            }


            for (HashMap<String,Object> album:albumList){
                System.out.println("Album Id : "+album.get("albumid").toString());
                System.out.println("Album Label : "+album.get("albumlabel").toString());
                System.out.println("Album Description : "+album.get("description").toString());
                System.out.println("Label : "+album.get("label").toString());
                System.out.println("Rating : "+album.get("rating").toString());
                System.out.println("Thumbnail : "+album.get("thumbnail").toString());
                System.out.println("Title : "+album.get("title").toString());
                System.out.println("Type : "+album.get("type").toString());
                System.out.println("Year : "+album.get("year").toString());
                System.out.println("Artist size : "+((ArrayList<String>)album.get("artist")).size());
                System.out.println("Artist Id size : "+((ArrayList<String>)album.get("artistid")).size());
                System.out.println("Genre size : "+((ArrayList<String>)album.get("genre")).size());
                System.out.println("Style size : "+((ArrayList<String>)album.get("style")).size());

            }

        }catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonPath to extract the artist arrays.

e.g. "$.result.albums[*].artist".

[JsonSurfer](https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer) would be a good choice if you are handling large json because it uses streaming parser without loading whole json into the memory.

The code is short with JsonSurfer.

```
JsonSurfer jsonSurfer = JsonSurfer.gson();
Collection<Object> result = jsonSurfer.collectAll(inputStreamReader, "$.result.albums[*].artist");
```